# point in polygon with `sf`

Tags: r, r-sf, point-in-polygon

i am trying to get that each point falls into the respective polygon. Given that I could not do it by aplying `sp::over` I am trying right now with the `tidyverse::sf` . I hope that someone can help me with this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIonJ.png)

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)
library(tidyverse)

# Point data

coordinates = st_as_sf(data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n = 100, min = -10, max = 10),0), , 2), id = 1:(100)), coords = c("X1", "X2"))
mapview::mapview(coordinates)


# Polygon data


DT <- fread("ID       NW.X     NW.Y       NE.X     NE.Y       SE.X     SE.Y       SW.X       SW.Y value
  1 -9.5 9.5  -0.5 9.5 -0.5 0.5 -9.5 0.5 7
  2 -9.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -9.5 -9.5 -9.5 14
  3 0.5 9.5 9.5 9.5 9.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 10
  4 0.5 -0.5 9.5 -0.5 9.5 -9.5 0.5 -9.5 8")

cols <- grep("^(NW|NE|SE|SW)\\.[XY]$", names(DT), value = TRUE)

DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", x))), .SDcols = cols]
#set to workable format df
buffers <- setDF(DT) %>%
  # Melt to long, beep XY paired
  pivot_longer( cols = cols,
                names_to = c("point", ".value"),
                names_pattern = "(..)\\.(.)" ) %>%
  sfheaders::sf_polygon( x = "X", y = "Y", polygon_id = "ID" )

#visual incpection
mapview::mapview(buffers)


## Both spatial types

mapview::mapview(buffers) %>%
  leafem::addStaticLabels(
    label = buffers$ID,
    noHide = TRUE,
    direction = 'top',
    textOnly = TRUE,
    textsize = "20px")

mapview::mapview(coordinates) %>%
  leafem::addStaticLabels(
    label = coordinates$id,
    noHide = TRUE,
    direction = 'top',
    textOnly = TRUE,
    offset = c(0, 0),
    textsize = "12px")


mapview::mapview(buffers) +  
  mapview::mapview(coordinates)
```

I want that each points goes from their respective figure (point-in-polygon)

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=coordinates) +
  geom_sf(data=buffers) +
  theme_minimal()


points_sf_joined <- st_join(coordinates, buffers) %>%
  filter(!is.na(coordinates$id))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=coordinates) +
  geom_sf(data=points_sf_joined) +
  theme_minimal()
```

With kind regards

Comment: are you just looking to intersect the points with your polygons?

Comment: Hello @D.J thank you for your answer, yes because there are 8 points which do not correspond to the polygons and are outside. I wanna have the polygons only with their respective points.

Comment: the default behaviour of `sf::st_join()` follows the left join logic of SQL (all elements of the first object are returned). Should you want filtering join (inner join in SQL speak) you will need to specify left = FALSE; for more info check the sf docs https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as posted is somewhat unclear - what exactly is the problem?

The way I read it is that you have the point-in-polygon problem already solved (via the `sf::st_join()` call). The id of each polygon is stored in the `ID` column of your points_sf_joinded object (the point id is in `id` column, which may be kind of confusing btw.)

See the result of your last plot, slightly amended by me (I have removed the plotting of original coordinates not assigned to a polygon, and color coded the polygon IDs).

I have also added a `geom_sf()` call for the polygons to be plotted.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = buffers) + # plot the polygons first
  geom_sf(data=points_sf_joined, aes(color = as.factor(ID))) +
  scale_color_brewer("polygon ID", palette = "Dark2") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: points in squares]

Comment: Hello @Jindra, I want a plot that are the same´as the screnshot which I added but with the points in their respective polygons. I do not want that the points are outside of the polygons. Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @Luis oki, I have updated the answer to plot the polygon squares as well...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jindra Lacko - it is not quite clear what the task is.

But as far as I understand you are looking for this:

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)
library(tidyverse)

## your code ##
# coordinates = ''
# DT <- ''
# cols <- ''
# DT['']
# buffers <- ''

res_list <- lapply(seq(nrow(buffers)), function(x) st_intersection(buffers[x,], coordinates))

res_list 


[[1]]
Simple feature collection with 18 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -9 ymin: 1 xmax: -1 ymax: 9
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
    ID id     geometry
1    1  6 POINT (-9 4)
1.1  1  9 POINT (-6 1)
1.2  1 11 POINT (-3 4)
1.3  1 13 POINT (-9 4)
1.4  1 24 POINT (-8 4)
1.5  1 26 POINT (-7 4)
1.6  1 31 POINT (-9 9)
1.7  1 35 POINT (-1 8)
1.8  1 45 POINT (-9 6)
1.9  1 56 POINT (-9 4)

...

[[4]]
Simple feature collection with 14 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: -7 xmax: 9 ymax: -1
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
    ID id     geometry
4    4  4 POINT (1 -3)
4.1  4 22 POINT (7 -4)
4.2  4 27 POINT (1 -3)
4.3  4 28 POINT (7 -2)
4.4  4 32 POINT (9 -7)
4.5  4 44 POINT (9 -1)
4.6  4 50 POINT (6 -5)
4.7  4 54 POINT (1 -3)
4.8  4 72 POINT (7 -4)
4.9  4 77 POINT (1 -3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was already solved but I will take your approach in mind :)